# Is it possible to access an RDC machine directory programmatically using C#

Tags: c#, directory

I have a remote desktop connection to another machine, with full access rights via username and password. Is there a way, using C#, to programmatically read directories and files on the RDC machine? Below is the code through which i have successfully made the connection with the rdc machine but how can i search for a specific directory? and then files in it. Any suggestion???

```
    ConnectionOptions connOptions = new ConnectionOptions();
    connOptions.Username = @"Salman\test123.req";
    connOptions.Password = "Test123";

    var scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\" + "86.30.300.400" + "\\root\\cimv2", connOptions);

    scope.Connect();

    //Query system for Operating System information
    var query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem");
    var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);

    ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection = searcher.Get();
    foreach (var m in queryCollection)
    {
        // Display the remote computer information
        Console.WriteLine("Computer Name : {0}", m["csname"]);
        Console.WriteLine("Windows Directory : {0}", m["WindowsDirectory"]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can search for a file name in a rdc machine

```
ConnectionOptions connOptions = new ConnectionOptions();
    connOptions.Username = @"Salman\test123.req";
    connOptions.Password = "Test123";

    var scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\" + "86.30.300.400" + "\\root\\cimv2", connOptions);

    scope.Connect();

    var searchString = "serie_"+TextBox1.Text;
    var query = new ObjectQuery(@"SELECT FileName from Cim_DataFile where path = '\\www\\folder1\\folder2\\' and Drive='D:' and FileName Like '"+searchString+"'");
    var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope,query);

    ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection = searcher.Get();


    foreach (var m in queryCollection)
    {
        TextBox1.Text = "Found";
    }
```